# Increment issue using for loop

Tags: bash

Is there a certain syntax to use while using fractions or decimals in a bash script?

I tried using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

{

n=9

echo "$n"

for (( i=.5; $i <10; i++ ));

  do
  let "c=$i+1"
  echo $i "+" $c
done

}
```

This works with i=1, but it generates a syntax error when I put .5.

Is there also a way to go by increments of 0.5 in the loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Not really. `bash` does not implement floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: No you cannot increment with decimal.
What can you do is multiply by a power of 10 what you need then divide back before you use in the code below.

Comment: also asked at http://askubuntu.com/q/365875/10127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really  want to use floating point in bash then you will find bc useful.

say you want 10 iterations, each of size 0.5

```
#!/bin/bash

Initial=1
Step=0.5
Count=10

for (( i=0; i < $Count; i++ ))
do
 Value=$(echo "$Initial + ( $Step * $i )" | bc)
 echo $Value
done
```

Will print:

```
$ ./t.sh 
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
3.5
4.0
4.5
5.0
5.5
```

Alternatively  exit the loop based upon Value thusly:

```
Initial=1
Step=0.5
Value=$Initial
TermValue=6.1

for (( i=0; $(echo "$Value < $TermValue" | bc); i++ ))
do
 Value=$(echo "$Value + $Step" | bc)
 echo $Value
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use floats in bash, but you can

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=5; $i <100; i+=10 )); do
    (( c = $i + 10 ))
    echo "${i: 0:-1}.${i: -1} + ${c: 0:-1}.${c: -1}"
done
```

i.e. multiply everything by 10 and then print the first `n-1` digits, a decimal point and then the last digit. Of course this is very limited in being useful.

Answer (score 0):

The shell itself won't support floats, but you can use bc if it's available, or awk, which is almost always available. Both will support floating point operations (so will perl, python, and some other tools)

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ printf ".%i %i 3.14\n" {1..16}
.1 2 3.14
.3 4 3.14
.5 6 3.14
.7 8 3.14
.9 10 3.14
.11 12 3.14
.13 14 3.14
.15 16 3.14

AirBoxOmega:~ d$ printf ".%i %i 3.14\n" {1..16}|awk '{print $1*$2/$3}'
0.0636943
0.382166
0.955414
1.78344
2.86624
0.420382
0.579618
0.764331

AirBoxOmega:~ d$ printf ".%i * %i /  3.14\n" {1..16}|bc -l
.06369426751592356687
.38216560509554140127
.95541401273885350318
1.78343949044585987261
2.86624203821656050955
.42038216560509554140
.57961783439490445859
.76433121019108280254
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq` and `bc`:

```
for i in $(seq 0.5 10);   do  
  c=$(echo "$i+1" | bc);   
  echo $i "+" $c; 
done
```